# Clean a maven repository - Delete all files except the x newest per folder

Tags: linux, maven

I would like to clean my local maven repository, but keep the last y snapshot versions for each artifact.

I found [this script](https://github.com/jettro/small-scripts/blob/master/groovy/CleanDir.groovy) but it works by date. 
I think I could adapt it to make it count files, but I'd like to know if such thing could be done directly with a linux find command.
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have an in-house repository manager it's probably simpler to clear your local repository and let it populate itself again over time.

If you do not have a repository manager, get one, even if it is just for yourself. I use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), but there are alternatives. Nexus let's you decide how many snapshots to keep and/or for how long. In the end it's going to be easier to manage artifact lifetime with Nexus rather than try to devise complicated scripts.

Comment: Yes i have a nexus but the problem is that i can't wipe out  the maven repository on my CI server because some internal artifacts are  not deployed to nexus, and i can't  rebuild them easily by the CI server because of cyclic build dependencies...
It's the combinaison of these 2 constraints that make me unable to delete the maven repo completely. I have to keep at least 1 version of each artifact that are not deployed to nexus.
I guess i should  resolve one of these 2 problems to be able to delete the maven CI repo, but i think it may be simpler to run a partial purge script :-)